# Find the next such set of prime numbers ending in 1, 3, 7, 9.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was checking this number theory exercise:

The numbers $11, 13, 17, 19$ are four odd integers ending in $1, 3,
7, 9$ that lie between two multiples of $10$. Find the next such set of prime
numbers ending in $1, 3, 7, 9$.

By trying several numbers I found the answer is $101,103,107,109$ but
I have been unable to find such numbers by a mathematic approximation or a different way.

If you have another way it will be really appreciated.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A007530

Comment: Well, by looking only divisibility by $3$, we can immediately throw out the $2/3$ of possibilities, leaving only $41,\dots$, then $71,\dots $ and $101,\dots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best optimization you can do by elementary means is to note that, like Berci said, with one exception, all these prime quadruples surround odd multiples of 15.

Algebraically, given $n \equiv 15 \pmod{30}$, we have $p = n - 4$, $p + 2 = n - 2$, $p + 6 = n + 2$ and $p + 8 = n + 4$.

So then there's no point in checking the 20s, because 21 is a nontrivial multiple of 3. Nor the 30s, for, even though 31 is prime, 33 is a nontrivial multiple of 3.

But do look at the 40s: we have 41, 43, 47... oh, dang, $49 = 7^2$. Actually, this suggests one other optimization, to swap 30 out for 210.

Then $n$ can be $15, 105, 195 \pmod{210}$. Looking at Sloane's http://oeis.org/A007530, you will see that except for 5, the lowest number $p$ of the prime quadruple is $11, 101, 191 \pmod{210}$.